# Ubuntu 20.04 installer not recognising windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, usb, windows

I want to install the latest ubuntu 20.04. I already have ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 on my computer. I can't upgrade it using update manager because my network is slower.So I downloaded a disk image and wrote it to a usb stick and tried to install. But the installer only says about ubuntu and not recognising my windows 10 . I'm afraid about its loss. What can I do? Please help

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. When in the booted Ubuntu, use `blkid` and/or `lsblk` from a Terminal to get an overview of the recognized partitions. If you're lucky you only overwrote something like the partition table and there are a host of "rescue" tools for the purpose, [including FLOSS ones](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Right now it sounds like you overwrote _something_, though. But your question is lacking details and it's not really about Ubuntu either (SuperUser would be the better Q&A site for this question).

Comment: Most common issue is Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. Windows turns this on with updates, so whenever the Linux NTFS driver does not correctly see the NTFS partitions check settings. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Windows needing chkdsk or SSD firmware not updated can also be issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it couple of times. I had Windows 10 on SSD, Ubuntu 18.04 in NVME. Separate storage . There were options in the GRUB menu to choose Windows 10 or Ubuntu on boot.

When I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in separate nvme (previous 18.04), GRUB did not find Windows 10. I tried running `grub-update` but it did not help.

I then again installed Windows 10 (previous was Windows 10, separate SSD). Then GRUB found it when I ran `sudo update-grub`. It's a weird issue.

If your Windows partition is intact, install Ubuntu 18.04 again . Ubuntu 18.04 will surely find Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I do also have a Desktop with SSD to the motherboard, running Windows 10.

I have the Second SSD with USB adapter, running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Works great. Very safe to protect your HDD with Winbdows 10.

just delete Ubuntu partition on your HDD and install Ubuntu on the Second SSD with USB adapter and you will have no issues.

https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/

Multi-booting on same drive, always causes issues when Windows 10 get new updates.

Answer (score -1):

Is the partitioner showing your HDD as empty? Your Windows partitions should be showing as "NTFS" and your Linux partitions as "ext4" or whichever FS format you selected when installing 18.04. I think there's an option to install 20.04 while saving your user data. Otherwise, you could back up the data you want to save, install 20.04 and then add the data back to the appropriate folders.

delta1071